# Unable to customize edit_form Flask-Admin: TypeError: edit_form() got an unexpected keyword argument 'obj'

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

My model is a dict of this kind:   {"category":category, "dish_name":dish_name, "index": index}   (the index is used just to force the products to be shown in a certain order)

In Flask-Admin i'm trying to customize its form in order to be able to change the product's category from a dropdown list of my categories (another mongodb collection).
I get prompted a textfield with the name and an empty selectfield. I think it's because the model doesn't actually contain all the categories, so the form "doesn't know" what to display.

I then tried to override edit_form() to force the categories list in the form, this way:

```
def edit_form(self, model):
    try:
        pk = self.get_pk_value(model)
        if not pk:
            raise ValueError('Document does not have _id')
        choices = list(db.db.categories.find())
        choices.sort(key=lambda x: x['order'])
        sorted_choices = [(cat['name'], cat['name']) for cat in choices]
        model['category'] = sorted_choices
        return super(MyModelView, self).edit_form(model)
    except Exception as ex:
        flash(gettext('Failed to edit product. %(error)s', error=str(ex)),
              'error')
        return False
```

But i get this error:

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\model\base.py", line 1264, in edit_view
form = self.edit_form(obj=model)
TypeError: edit_form() got an unexpected keyword argument 'obj'
```

Which is very confusing to me, since the 'obj' argument doesn't seem unexpected at all...

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess: flask-admin calls the `edit_form` function with a named keyword variable `obj`, while you have named it `model`. This is why for your version of `edit_form` the `obj` variable is "unexpected". Try to change your function signature to

```
def edit_form(self, obj):
```

and also change `model` to `obj` in the function body, does that help?